# Adding Captions to Featherlight

Tags: jquery, featherlight.js

I was reading [this](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/wiki/Gallery:-showing-a-caption) to add caption text to the lightbox. I have this rather simple HTML code:

```
<div class="icon-click-img">
  <a href="img.jpg" data-featherlight="image" >
    <img src="some-icon.png" height="83" width="83" />
  </a>
</div>
<img class="img-responsive" src="img.url" alt="alt">
```

If I wanted to add something like:

```
<script>
  jQuery.featherlightGallery.prototype.afterContent = function() {
    var caption = this.$currentTarget.find('img').attr('alt');
    this.$instance.find('.caption').remove();
    $('<div class="caption">').text(caption).appendTo(this.$instance.find('.featherlight-content'));
  };
</script>
```

I'm not sure how it would work because the lightbox image is a link to an image, therefore it doesn't have an ALT tag. How can I make captions appear with the code I already have? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Late reply, but I was looking for this myself.

Anyhow. First off, images should always have an alt tag (screenreaders, image failed to load, ...)

Working Solution (I left out all of my php and bootstrapping code)

```
<div data-featherlight-gallery data-featherlight-filter="a">
    <a class="gallery" href="big_image.jpg">
        <img title="Small Image" src="small_image.jpg" alt="Small Image Caption" />
    </a>
</div>

<script>
    $.featherlightGallery.prototype.afterContent = function () {
        var caption = this.$currentTarget.find('img').attr('title');
        this.$instance.find('.caption').remove();
        $('<div class="caption">').text(caption).appendTo(this.$instance.find('.featherlight-content'));
    }
</script>
```

Edit: Instead of the alt attribute I prefered the title attribute but, it's the same thing. You can pick any attribute. Just change the attr in the script